# DIV ID for Modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several instances of a modal window with a triggering button for each. When I press a button to activate the specific modal the same one appears for all buttons. I thought it was the DIV ID and changed the names but it is still happening.

This is for my personal portfolio site and if anyone who helps would like some graphic work done I would be very happy to help

Each modal window is an example of my work and should pop up in it own window instead of the same content popping up in all.

I appreciate any and all help offered and would extend to the those who provide the solution my services as a graphic designer.

I included a sample below.

```
<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<article class="portfolio-item pf-uielements pf-media">
  <div class="portfolio-desc">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
      <img src="assets/img/mobile.png" alt="Rockefeller Capital Management">Rockefeller Capital<span>Mobile </span></button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - start
                ================= -->

  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Rockefeller Capital • Mobile Application</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- Portfolio Single Gallery
                ============================================= -->

            <div class="col_full portfolio-single-image">
              <div class="fslider" data-arrows="true" data-animation="slide">
                <div class="flexslider">
                  <div class="slider-wrap">
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/rcm/RCG_contact.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/rcm/Dashboard-alt_Dark-Theme.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/rcm/Dashboard-alt_iteration-3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-image end -->

            <div class="col_one_third nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="card events-meta">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="portfolio-meta nobottommargin">
                    <li><span><i class="icon-user"></i>Created by:</span> James Smith</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Skills:</span> Sketch • Invision • Illustrator</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-link"></i>Client:</span> <a href="https://rcm.rockco.com/">Rockefeller Capital Management</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta End -->

            </div>

            <!-- Portfolio Single Content
                ============================================= -->
            <div class="col_two_third portfolio-single-content col_last nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="fancy-title title-dotted-border">
                <h2>Project Brief</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half nobottommargin">
                <p>A mobile application designed to provide their customers the same functioanlity of the website regradless of their location can perform the saame various financial operations they are accustomed to via their cell phone or tablet.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half col_last nobottommargin">
                <p>When creating the mobile app the research we conducted was distilled into the two most important qualities that they (users) wanted, security and simplicity. From this a list of best practices for developers and users was generated focused on reducing or completely eliminating potential safety risks and I crafted this into a social media strategy.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description End -->

            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-content end -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - end
                ================= -->
</article>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<article class="portfolio-item pf-uielements pf-media">
  <div class="portfolio-desc">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
      <img src="assets/img/mobile.png" alt="Rockefeller Capital Management">King Melvin<span>Mobile</span></button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - start
                ================= -->

  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="kingmelvin">King Melvin • Mobile Application</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- Portfolio Single Gallery
                ============================================= -->

            <div class="col_full portfolio-single-image">
              <div class="fslider" data-arrows="true" data-animation="slide">
                <div class="flexslider">
                  <div class="slider-wrap">
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/km/KM_S_1.png" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/km/KM_S_2.png" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/km/KM_S_3.png" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/km/KM_S_4.png" alt=""></a></div>
                    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/km/KM_S_5.png" alt=""></a></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-image end -->

            <div class="col_one_third nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="card events-meta">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="portfolio-meta nobottommargin">
                    <li><span><i class="icon-user"></i>Created by:</span> James Smith</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Skills:</span> Adobe XD • Photoshop • Illustrator</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-link"></i>Client:</span> <a href="https://King Melvin.com/">King Melvin</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta End -->

            </div>

            <!-- Portfolio Single Content
                ============================================= -->
            <div class="col_two_third portfolio-single-content col_last nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="fancy-title title-dotted-border">
                <h2>Project Brief</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half nobottommargin">
                <p>King Melvin is your evening companion that always knows where to go and consistently makes the best suggestions the liven up the mood and give you the best offers the night has out there for you and your group of friends.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half col_last nobottommargin">
                <p>From commissioned research these identified 4 industries are traditionally associated with weekend festivities limited in their access to traditional marketing channels. This aggregate portal will provide a direct pipeline to their customers.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description End -->

            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-content end -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - end
                ================= -->
</article>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<article class="portfolio-item pf-uielements pf-media">
  <div class="portfolio-desc">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
      <img src="assets/img/video.png" alt="Rockefeller Capital Management">Morgan Stanley<span>Video </span></button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - start
                ================= -->

  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="morganstanley">Morgan Stanley • Global Creative Services Promo</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- Portfolio Single Gallery
                ============================================= -->

            <div class="col_full portfolio-single-image">
              <div class="center clearfix" style="padding: 50px;">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/139208268?badge=0" width="500" height="210" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-image end -->

            <div class="col_one_third nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="card events-meta">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <ul class="portfolio-meta nobottommargin">
                    <li><span><i class="icon-user"></i>Created by:</span> James Smith</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-lightbulb"></i>Skills:</span> Sketch • Invision • Illustrator</li>
                    <li><span><i class="icon-link"></i>Client:</span> <a href="https://rcm.rockco.com/">Rockefeller Capital Management</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Meta End -->

            </div>

            <!-- Portfolio Single Content
                ============================================= -->
            <div class="col_two_third portfolio-single-content col_last nobottommargin">

              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description
                ============================================= -->
              <div class="fancy-title title-dotted-border">
                <h2>Project Brief</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half nobottommargin">
                <p>ZZZ.</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col_half col_last nobottommargin">
                <p>zzz.</p>
              </div>
              <!-- Portfolio Single - Description End -->

            </div>
            <!-- .portfolio-single-content end -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal - end
                ================= -->
</article>
```

Comment: You use the same `data-target` attribute for all of your buttons. `data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"` So of course they will all open the same model. Give your modals unique IDs. Use the correct ID in the `data-target` attribute.

Comment: as @Turnip said, an ID must be unique for each button. As a general rule when you define an ID for anything make sure your ID is unique.